# Connect Ble is not working in android using esp provisioning call

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi in the below code I am trying to connecting to ble using esp provisioning call. But it is not connected .

I am getting the list of devices near by and comparing device name prefix if it matches I am connecting to ble. list is getting and not connecting to device.

Can any one help me where I did the mistake.

```
String bleName = jObj.optString(PesConstants.BLE_NAME); // BLE_NAME | for testing
                    String pop = jObj.optString(PesConstants.POP_NAME);
                    scanDevice(context, "PESPROV_", bleName);
                    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                    if (bluetoothAdapter != null && bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
  
                        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                    }
                    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                            String action = intent.getAction();
                            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                                bluetoothDevices = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                            
                              
                                if (bluetoothDevices != null) {
                                    String prefix = "PESPROV_" + bleName;

                                    if (prefix.equals(bluetoothDevices.get("name"))) {

                                        String device = Util.convertBase64ToString(prefix);
                                   
                                        BleDevice bluetoothDevice = new Gson().fromJson(device, BleDevice.class);
                                        BluetoothDevice connectedBluetooth = pesManager.getBleDevice(bluetoothDevice.getMacAddress());
                                        pesManager.connectBleDevices(connectedBluetooth, bluetoothDevice.getServiceUUid());
                                        pesManager.getEspDevice().setProofOfPossession(pop);
                                        String wifiAccesspointName = jObj.optString(Constant.SSID);
                                        String wifiAccesspointPassword = jObj.optString(Constant.PASS_PHASE);
                                        try {
                                            pesManager.provision(wifiAccesspointName, wifiAccesspointPassword);
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        pesManager.initPesDevice((Activity) context, bleName);
                                        String nonceStr = ""; //uri.getQueryParameter(PesConstants.NONCE); // // stable
                                        String provUrl = "";//uri.getQueryParameter(PesConstants.PROVISIONING_URL); // //provision
                                        pesManager.sendPesNonce(provUrl, nonceStr);
                                        //Timber.tag("PES").i("PesNative-Inside performPesConnectivity method | Completed Executing sendNonce Api Call");
                                        checkAPIExecutedTime(loggingData);
                                    }
                                }
                                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    // TODO: Consider calling
                                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                                    return;
                                }

                                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                        // TODO: Consider calling
                                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                                        return;
                                    }

                            }
                        }
                    };
                    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                    context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,filter);
                }
```

Comment: I think bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery() only finds Bluetooth Classic devices. You need to use the BLE API to find BLE devices.